# logback settings and spring config-server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud, microservices

There are many of microservices, all of them should write logs to  the same graylog server. In every of microservices is used a GelfLogbackAppender which has several settings like host, post and etc. These setting are the same for all of services and i want to store them in one place like a spring config-server. How can i do that? How can i get and use GELF_ADDRESS from config-server?

```
<appender name="gelf" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender">
    <host>udp:${GELF_ADDRESS}</host>
    <port>${GELF_PORT}</port>
```

**UPDATE** I've decided to show simple example what i want to, let's imagine i want to change log level for all microservices through config-server. i make next things:

**logback-spring.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property name="LEVEL" value="${log_level}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <root level="${LEVEL}">
         <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**application.yml** is being in config-server

```
eureka:
  client:....
feign:
  hystrix:....
log_level: info
```

it doesn't work, i always see DEBUG level, if i write

```
<property name="LEVEL" value="info"/>
```

manualy into  logback-spring.xml, the level will be changed, but i want to do that through central config-serverer

Answer (score 0):

Define GELF_ADDRESS property in application specific properties in config-server and try reading it using config client configuration in respective application

Follow this tutorial to set up Config Server https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/
and to read the property in config client

Define below property in app.properties:

app.properties

```
GELF_ADDRESS=<<value to be set>>
```

Update 1:

I tried with sample. Check this out : https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/Spring-Task-Sample/tree/master/Logback-configuration-configserver

Comment: i am already using config-server for other settings for microservices, but when i just put GELF_ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1  into general application.yml which is being into config-server then it doesn't work

Comment: provide your code to comment further. Also check the logs on url formed in config client to fetch the property sources from config server and more importantly put spring.cloud.config.uri in bootstrap.yml

Comment: i've added a new example in my post.
other business setting are loadded from config-server normally, i see that.

Answer (score 0):

to use spring property from **application.properties**, need to collect it using this line in configuration element

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="LEVEL" source="log_level"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific question seems to be about the graylog URL getting set through spring cloud config. I found that graylog sets that value immediately on startup, but there is a property you can set in the logback config to update your graylog properties after startup.

https://www.baeldung.com/logback

Section 6.4 of the above link describes automatically reloading your logging config. Specifically the need for the scan property on the configuration tag.

In short you set up your configuration to scan for updates which would allow logback to pull in the cloud config properties even after startup. (Note: if you have the configuration tag set with debug="true" you'll see logback starts its configuration before cloud config grabs the properties.)

In total the xml should look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="1 minute">
    <springProperty scope="context" name="GRAY_LOG_HOST" source="cloud.config.property.for.graylog.server"   defaultValue="mygraylogdefault.com"/>
    <appender name="TCP" class="de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfTcpAppender">
        <graylogHost>${GRAY_LOG_HOST}</graylogHost>
        <graylogPort>12201</graylogPort>
    </appender>
    <appender name="GELF" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="TCP" />
    </appender>
    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="GELF"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```